# How a class having only the '__getitem__' method defined support the 'in' operator?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, python-collections

If I have the following defined:

```
Card = namedtuple('Card', ['rank', 'suit'])

class CardDeck():
  ranks = [str(x) for x in range(2, 11)] + list('JQKA')
  suits = 'spades diamonds clubs hearts'.split()

  def __init__(self):
    self._cards = [Card(rank, suit) for rank in self.ranks for suit in self.suits]

  def __getitem__(self, index):
    return self._cards[index]
```

How the `in` operator is supported without having the `__contains__` dunder method defined. For example the following:

```
deck = CardDeck()
print(Card('2', 'hearts') in deck)
```

will output:

```
True
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Put `print('something')` in `__getitem__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__getitem__` is used as a fallback when no [`__contains__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__) or [`__iter__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iter__) is available. See the [*Membership test operations* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) of the *expressions* reference documentation:

> Lastly, the old-style iteration protocol is tried: if a class defines `__getitem__()`, `x in y` is `True` if and only if there is a non-negative integer index *i* such that `x is y[i] or x == y[i]`, and no lower integer index raises the `IndexError` exception.

So what actually happens is that Python simply uses an increasing index, which in Python would look something like this:

```
from itertools import count

def contains_via_getitem(container, value):
    for i in count():   # increments indefinitely
        try:
            item = container[i]
            if value is item or value == item:
                return True
        except IndexError:
            return False
```

This treatment extends to all iteration functionality. Containers that do not implement `__iter__` but do implement `__getitem__` can still have an iterator created for them (with `iter()` or the C-API equivalent):

```
>>> class Container:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self._items = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
...     def __getitem__(self, index):
...         return self._items[index]
...
>>> c = Container()
>>> iter(c)
<iterator object at 0x1101596a0>
>>> list(iter(c))
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Containment tests via iteration are, of course, not really efficient. If there is a way to determine if something is an item in the container without a full scan, do implement a `__contains__` method to provide that better implementation!

For a card deck, I can imagine that simply returning `True` when the item is a `Card` instance should suffice (provided the `Card` class validates the rank and suit parameters):

```
def __contains__(self, item):
    # a card deck contains all possible cards
    return isinstance(item, Card)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [the documemtation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__)

```
object.__contains__(self, item)   ...

 For objects that don’t define __contains__(), the membership test
 first tries iteration via __iter__(), then the old sequence iteration
 protocol via __getitem__(),...
```

[see this section in the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details).

Comment: Oh, beautiful, that's **exactly** the docs part that is relevant here.